# How to remove a specific part of a link whilst redirecting in PHP?

Tags: php

I was looking at other places and it seems to be confusing me still.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

Here is the link: `https://example.com/redirect/abc?123`

And I'd like it to redirect to the page: `https://example.com/newlink/abc` - Which removes the `?123` and redirecting to that

Edit:
The website specifically is a shortlink website and theres a website that does it but adds something next to the link like `https://example.com/newlink/NewLink?SomethingHere` which then breaks it - I'm trying to find a way to remove the `?SomethingHere` part, if you get what I mean.

How would I do that in PHP specifically?

Comment: What problem are you having? Just put the base URL in the `header("Location: ...")` call.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `parse_url()` which breaks up the parts of a URL into an assoc array, you can simply do

```
$url = 'https://example.com/redirect/abc?123';
$bits = parse_url($url);

$NewLocation = $bits['scheme'] . '://' . $bits['host'] . $bits['path'];
echo $NewLocation;
```

RESULT

```
https://example.com/redirect/abc
```

If you were to `print_r($bits)` you would see the array like this

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => example.com
    [path] => /redirect/abc
    [query] => 123
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok` function to remove the parameters after the URL, and use the following instruction `header("Location: ...")` to perform the redirection.

Take a look at the following example:

```php
 $url = strtok($url, '?');
 header("Location: $url")
```